# XNA DrawableGameComponent mouse input problem

Tags: xna, mouse, drawablegamecomponent

I'm developing a simple board game, where my game board is represented as a DrawableGameComponent. In the update method of board I'm checking mouse input to determine which field on the board was clicked. The problem I'm encountering is that mouse click gets registered only once every 5-6 clicks.

Mouse click code is basic:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        Point mouseCell = new Point(-1, -1);

        if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
        {
            mouseCell = new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
        }

        // cell calc ...

        previousMouseState = mouseState;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

In the Game.cs, I'm just adding my board to Components collection.

Has anyone idea what I might be missing here?

EDIT: Actually, it's not just the mouse, keyboard input doesn't work properly either, so I've probably messed up DrawableGameComponent implementation altrough I have no idea how.

EDIT2: Found some folks here: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/23752/128804.aspx and here: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/71524.aspx having very similar problems. 
After unsuccessful debugging I ditched the DrawableGameComponent and implemented manual LoadContent/Update/Draw calls and put all input collecting into game.cs. Works like a charm.
However, if someone has any explanation what could have went wrong (looks like DrawableGameComponent somehow clodges input) I'd really like to know.

Comment: Do a search in your solution and try to find another place you might have used mouse / keyboard GetState. I'm not sure with XNA, but it's possible you do a GetEvent somewhere else, and that resets the keyboard/mouse states.

Comment: Do you have many GameComponent instances registered? what else is being updated in your game?

Comment: @Marking: That certainly could happen, but the GetState was called only once.

Comment: @liortal: Problem was there even with only one GameComponent instance, and that mouse code stated above was the only update code.

Comment: How do you know that the mouse click is registered only every 5-6 clicks? what is your reference that the click got hit or not? In your mouse hit detector (inside the body of the IF you posted here), add a line to call Debug.WriteLine("Mouse Clicked.");    then start your game, hit the mouse left button, see in the Output view of Visual Studio if this text is written on every click, or on every 5-6 clicks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that if the mouse changes state between `MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();` and `previousMouseState = mouseState;`, then `previousMouseState` and `mouseState` will have the same value.

This can be maked almost imposible by moving those to lines as close to each other as posible.

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Point mouseCell = new Point(-1, -1); //moved this up, so that the mouseState and previousMouseState are as close to each other as possible.
    MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        mouseCell = new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
    }
    //It is almost imposible, that the mouse has changed state before this point
    previousMouseState = mouseState; //The earliest place you can possibly place this line...

    // cell calc ...

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```